# Adding a Picture to an Imagebutton programmatically(Android)

Tags: android, mobile

Basically i just want to add a picture to an Imagebutton if i normally create this Imagabutton in XML it works. But if i try the same thing in Java the App crashes.

My Java looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        TableLayout t = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.game_field);
        ImageButton b1 = new ImageButton (this);
        t.addView(b1,params);
```

if i do it like this it works without a problem but if i add this line:

```
b1.setImageResource(R.drawable.blackbutton);
```

the app crashes

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I solved this problem through scaling the pictures smaller outside of Android Studio. But i got a new Problem now as i wanted to scale the Imagebutton a little bit more in Android Studio with layoutparams. It crashes again. i dont know what you would like to see? the run log?

Comment: scale it what sense, make the image inside the image button smaller inside android studio? or change the width and height of the imagebutton inside the layout?

Comment: I'd like to change the size of the imagebutton to make them fit as i want create a field of 10x10.

Comment: so you want 10 imagebuttons wide and 10 imagebuttons high in a tableLayout?

Comment: Yes 10 rows with 10 Imagebuttons in it . They should not fill the entire screen just the table layout which is just a part of my xml hierarchy

Comment: So I'm gettin the height and width of the Tablelayout divide it by 10 and put them together in a layout param which i add to the button. And this 'scaling' of the buttons and pictures inside which have to scaletype Fit_xy seems to make the app crashing. By the way i did set padding to zero

Comment: okay, let me have a think ill get back to you a little later